# Using System.Windows.SystemParameters not working (cannot import presentationframework.dll)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and I'm running into a problem with referencing presentationframework.dll. From the tutorials I've read, the "add reference" tab doesn't show up, and the "add project reference" and "add shared project reference" contents are completely empty[image: No "Add Reference" Showing]

Is there a way to fix this? I'm using .NET framework 5.0 with a Console Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `PresentationFramework.dll`, you need to create a WPF project. Also, you can't add references in .NET 5 and Core, only in .NET Framework.

---

**BUT**... there is a workaround!

Unload your project, then click `Edit project file` in the right-click context menu.

Then, add this to your .csproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After that, save and reload your project. You should be able to use `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width` and `...Height`.

Comment: If this worked for you, kindly mark it as an answer by clicking the checkmark below the vote buttons. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to implement it into a Console App? If not, how can I get the screen dimensions using it? Edit: I only see ".net 5.0" and ".net Core 3.1"

Comment: Please check the answer again. I've added a workaround.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help